# testing failed promises with mocha's built-in promise support

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js

How should I be testing, with mocha and chai, that my promise has failed?

I am confused, because I initially thought I should be using 'mocha-as-promised', but that
package is now deprecated (I'm using mocha 2.1.0), with the advice to
just use the promise testing that's now built into mocha.
see: https://github.com/domenic/mocha-as-promised

Another post recommends doing away with the 'done' argument to the
it() callback - not sure I understand why, since my understanding that
passing in the 'done' parameter was the way to signal that a test was
being tested asynchronously.
see: [How do I properly test promises with mocha and chai?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571328/how-to-i-properly-test-promises-with-mocha-and-chai)

Anyway, I've tried to reduce my issue to the below code - please help me modify this so that I can test that my promise indeed fails.

```
it.only("do something (negative test)", function (done) {

  var Q = require('q');

  function makePromise() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.reject(Error('fail'));
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  makePromise()
  .then(done, done);

});
```

Answer (score 9):

Some more digging, and it appears the right way is to add an additional catch block, like so...

```
it.only("do something (negative test)", function (done) {

  var Q = require('q');

  function makePromise() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.reject(Error('fail'));
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  makePromise()
  .catch(function(e) {
    expect(e.message).to.equal('fail');
  })
  .then(done, done);

});
```

I'm interested in alternative ideas, or confirmation that this is fine the way it is.. thanks.

UPDATE:

*Ben - I now grok what you were saying, esp. after the terse but helpful comment from Benjamin G.*

To summarize:

When you pass in a `done` parameter, the test is expected to trigger it's 'done-ness' by calling the `done()` function;

When you don't pass in a `done` parameter, it normally only works for synchronous calls. However,
if you ***return*** a promise, the mocha framework (mocha >1.18) will catch any failures that normally  would have been swallowed (per the promises spec). Here is an updated version:

```
it.only("standalone neg test for mocha+promises", function () {

  var Q = require('q');

  function makePromise() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.reject(Error('fail'));
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return makePromise()
  .catch(function(e) {
    expect(e.message).to.equal('fail');
  });

});
```

Comment: You can `return ` the `makePromise()` and remove the `done, done` part.

Comment: I would add an extra assertion to make sure that it did not hit the acceptance case.

`return makePromise()
.then(() => {
          // Acceptance case, we should not get here.
          expect().fail('exception did not appear to be thrown');
        }, (e) => {
          // Failure case, we should get here and the message shoudl match
          expect(e.message).to.equal('fail');
        });
`

Answer (score 3):

You can return a promise to signal that the test is asynchronous:

```
function something() {
  return Q.reject(Error('fail'));
}

it('should reject', function() {
  return something().then(function() {
    throw new Error('expected rejection');
  },
  function() {
    return 'passed :]';
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`chai-as-promised` provides a clean testing framework for Promises:

```
$ npm install chai-as-promised
```

In your test file:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

...

it('resolves as promised', function() {
    return expect(Promise.resolve('woof')).to.eventually.equal('woof');
});

it('rejects as promised', function() {
    return expect(Promise.reject('caw')).to.be.rejectedWith('caw');
});
```

This feels clean and intuitive.  But you can accomplish something similar without chai-as-promised like this:

```
it('resolved as promised', function() {
    return Promise.resolve("woof")
        .then(function(m) { expect(m).to.equal('woof'); })
        .catch(function(m) { throw new Error('was not supposed to fail'); })
            ;
});

it('rejects as promised', function() {
    return Promise.reject("caw")
        .then(function(m) { throw new Error('was not supposed to succeed'); })
        .catch(function(m) { expect(m).to.equal('caw'); })
            ;
});
```

Comment: I am trying to use chai-as-promised, my async method returns promise of deferred library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred). When I am running the test I am getting below error. does deferred supported by this mudule ?
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: @PiyushBeli: make sure the form that "feeds" the `then` returns a promise.  For example, make sure it has a return statement in it.