# Testing rejected promise in Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, bluebird, chai-as-promised

I have a class that rejects a promise:

```
Sync.prototype.doCall = function(verb, method, data) {
  var self = this;

  self.client = P.promisifyAll(new Client());

  var res = this.queue.then(function() {
    return self.client.callAsync(verb, method, data)
      .then(function(res) {
        return;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {    
        // This is what gets called in my test    
        return P.reject('Boo');
      });
  });

  this.queue = res.delay(this.options.throttle * 1000);
  return res;
};

Sync.prototype.sendNote = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  return self.doCall('POST', '/Invoice', {
    Invoice: data
  }).then(function(res) {
    return data;
  });
};
```

In my test:

```
return expect(s.sendNote(data)).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Boo');
```

However while the test passes it throws the error to the console.

Unhandled rejection Error: Boo
   ...

With non promise errors I have used bind to test to prevent the error from being thrown until Chai could wrap and test:

```
return expect(s.sendNote.bind(s, data)).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Boo');
```

However this does not work with this and returns:

TypeError: `[Function] is not a thenable.`

What is the correct way to test for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error because sendNote is being rejected and you're not catching it.

Try:

```
var callPromise = self.doCall('POST', '/Invoice', {
  Invoice: data
}).then(function(res) {
  return data;
});

callPromise.catch(function(reason) {
  console.info('sendNote failed with reason:', reason);
});

return callPromise;
```

Looks like you'll also have to move your existing catch one block out:

```
var res = this.queue.then(function() {
  return self.client.callAsync(verb, method, data)
    .then(function(res) {
      return;
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {    
    // This is what gets called in my test    
    return P.reject('Boo');
  });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. Still dumps error on console

Comment: I think it has to do with the queue. If I just do `return P.reject()` from the `doCall` function it works

Comment: Ah. Move the catch one block out.

Comment: Yes - I added a catch to the `res.delay` call and it worked. Sweet! If you'll update your answer I will mark it.

Comment: the then block does nothing, it can be removed.

Comment: @mido22 The code could be cleaned up a lot; The question wasn't about how to clean up the rest of the code.

Answer (score 36):

(Disclaimer: This is a good question even for people that do not use Bluebird.  I've posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222332/558639); this answer will work for people that aren't using Bluebird.)

#### with chai-as-promised

Here's how you can use chai-as-promised to test both `resolve` and `reject` cases for a Promise:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

...

it('resolves as promised', function() {
    return expect(Promise.resolve('woof')).to.eventually.equal('woof');
});

it('rejects as promised', function() {
    return expect(Promise.reject('caw')).to.be.rejectedWith('caw');
});
```

#### without chai-as-promised

You can accomplish the same without chai-as-promised like this:

```
it('resolves as promised', function() {
  return Promise.resolve("woof")
    .then(function(m) { expect(m).to.equal('woof'); })
    .catch(function(e) { throw e })  // use error thrown by test suite
           ;
});

it('rejects as promised', function() {
    return Promise.reject("caw")
        .then(function(m) { throw new Error('was not supposed to succeed'); })
        .catch(function(m) { expect(m).to.equal('caw'); })
            ;
});
```

Comment: Without using `chai-as-promised`, you could instead throw the error generated by the test suite.

`.catch(function(e) { throw e });`

Comment: @IliasT - you are so very correct that I've incorporated your suggestion.  Hope you don't mind!  :)

Comment: Before using this solution, see Sylvain's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119610/2136313

Answer (score 14):

I personally use that idiom:

```
it('rejects as promised', function() {
    return Promise.reject("caw")
        .then(
          (m) => { assert.fail('was not supposed to succeed'); }
          (m) => { /* some extra tests here */ }
        );
});
```

This is one of the rare cases `then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` (2 arguments) is legitimate to use.

If you chain `.then(reject).catch(onRejected)` as suggested in other answers, you end up entering in the `catch` handler *every time* since it will catch as well the rejection produced in the preceding `then` handler--which could cause evergreen tests if you're not careful enough to check that eventuality.

Answer (score 1):

**generic helper function:**

```js
import { assert } from 'chai'

const assertThrowsAsync = async(fn, expectedMessage) => {
    try {
        await fn()
    } catch (err) {
        if (expectedMessage) {
            assert.include(err.message, expectedMessage, `Function failed as expected, but could not find message snippet '${expectedMessage}'`)
        }
        return
    }
    assert.fail('function did not throw as expected')
}
```

**calling it like so:**

```js
describe('demo', () => {

    it('negative: inacceptable path', async() => {
        await assertThrowsAsync(async() => {
            await someFuntionOfMine({}, ['/really/bad/path'])
        }, 'acceptable path')
    })

    ...
```