# How to Test throwing Errors in Mocha

Tags: javascript, ethereum, truffle

I am trying to test my contract with Mocha.
So far, my solution has been this:

```
it("transfers token ownership", async () => {
        const tokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed()
        expect(async () => { await tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 9999999999999999999) }).to.throw('user has insufficient funds');
    })
```

But I get this error:
`AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error`

Any idea how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: It *doesn't* throw an error - it's returning a promise, it *rejects*. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31845329/3001761.

Comment: Doesn't the arrow function given to the expect need to be invoked?  `expect()` is not going to invoke a callback given to it.  It is expect to be given a value to behave against.  At least that is my experience with most jasmine like testing suites.

Comment: Try it without the extra arrow function.  `expect(await tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 9999999999999999999))`.  though that might not address an issue jon is pointing out