# Unit testing NodeJS Promise inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Im trying to unit test a function that calls a promise...

Using Mocha, Sinon. I have a functional block like this:

myfile.js:

```
    let OuterDependecy = require('mydep');
    function TestFunction(callback) {
        OuterDependency.PromiseFunction().then(response => {  

       //some logic here
     }).catch(err => {callback(err)});
```

inside my test i have used [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to mock the outerdependecy

testfile.js

```
let proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
let OuterDepStub = {};
let testingFunc = proxyquire('myfile.js', {'mydep': OuterDepStub});
```

... then inside my testing block

```
    let stubCallback = function() {
                console.log('Stub dubadub dub'); //note...i can use sinon.spy here instead
    };

   beforeEach(()=>{
            OuterDependency.PromiseFunction = function(arg) {
               return  new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                   reject('BAD');
               });
            };


            spy = sinon.spy(stubCallback);
       });
```

my actual test now calls the main "testfunction"

```
it('Catches Errors, and calls back using error', done => {
            TestFunction(stubCallback);
            expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
            done();
        });
```

I see the stub being called (the console log, hence why i didnt want to use sinon.spy)  but the spy is saying its not called. and unit test fails.

I believe this is probably due to a race condition of sorts where the promise is resolving after my test is run... is there anyway to delay the test until my promise is resolve.

i know in in angularjs promise testing, there was a way to "tick" the promise so it resolves when you want to. possible in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- > is there anyway to delay the test until my promise is resolve.

As far as I understand your issue, yes, you should only call `done()` **after the promise is settled**. In order to do that,you need two things:

1- Enforce `TestFunction` to **return** a Promise, so you can wait until it resolves:

```
    function TestFunction(callback) {
     return OuterDependency.PromiseFunction().then(response => {

        //some logic here
    }).catch(err => { callback(err) });
}
```

2- Wait to that promise to settle, then call `done`.

```
it('Catches Errors, and calls back using error', done => {
    TestFunction(stubCallback).then(() => {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
        done();
    })
});
```

now, our `then` block won't run until the `catch` block within `TestFunction`, so if the test works as expected (i.e. the catch block fires and the callback gets fired), **the expectation and the done calls will always fire after the callback gets called**.

- > I see the stub being called (the console log, hence why i didnt want to use sinon.spy) but the spy is saying its not called. and unit test fails.

That's because your expectation runs right after the `TestFunction` calls, without waiting for it to settle. However, it **will** get called lately, thus the `console.log` appears in the next spec.

Comment: so bad! did someone change when you tried? Like the order of the `console.log` statements? Are you sure `TestFunction` is actually failing?

Comment: I checked in webstorm debug test...and my assumption was correct,

the stub part is being called AFTER my unit test. 

The testfunction does fail (i.e it does call stub)

Comment: @nate The above answer is mostly correct, but you need to use `.catch()`, not `.then()`, because in your stub you reject the promise. See this SO answer, although there are other ways of doing the rejection catch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704791/testing-failed-promises-with-mochas-built-in-promise-support

Comment: Yep @DanielT. you are right....that worked.

It still sucks though in nodejs there doesnt seem to be  a way to resolve promises "globally" 

so that you dont have to return a promise from the main function