# Mocha exceeding 2000ms timeout when returning a promise

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to test my Express.js controllers but every so often I run into a problem with the mocha timeout telling me off.

The docs (https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) and the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572442/1646372 state that I can just return the promise I'm using.

I've wrapped my express controllers with Promises so that I can then return them in the tests.

I have a basic test that I can run to consistently get the error message:

```
it('should return', () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('hello');
    }, 2300);
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I don't understand why the error is present as I'm returning a promise that does resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set timeout in the command line with this flag `--timeout 5000` or you can add this at first line of a test `this.timeout(5000);`, under describe statement, inside the function.

Comment: You write a timeout of 2300 it's normal that you exceed the 2000 default time!

Comment: Sorry, it just clicked that the mocha timeout is the final curtain close. I was thinking that if you return a promise, the timeout gets cancelled and you're allowed as much time as you want. And now I think about that, that would be very dangerous

Comment: Hahahah nevermind friend!