# Handle Promise rejection case Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, sinon

If I comment the line `return Promise.reject(err);` in my `findGood` function, the test case should fail. Meaning that, if I'm not returning from my function, the `catch` block in the test should be `undefined`.

```
var findGood = function (name) {

    return goodModel.findByName(name)
        .then( (result) => {

            ....
            return result;


        })
        .catch( (err) => {          
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }); 
};
```

Here is a test

```
it('good not found', function () {

   var goodModelStub = sinon.stub(goodModel, 'findByName');

   var error = 'Good not found';

   goodModelStub.returns(Promise.reject(error));

   return goodFinder.findGood('Sony')
     .catch(function (err) {
         assert.equal(err, error);
  });
```

});

Comment: `.catch( (err) => Promise.reject(err))` is pretty much a useless statement, as you'd get the exact same behavior if you just removed it.

Comment: @Frxstrem then what should i do? can you pls answer if you know?

Comment: you must call the promise, like real, not directly to catch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571328/how-do-i-properly-test-promises-with-mocha-and-chai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there's no need to catch an error and then throw it again, handle the rejection in the proper place (your test case in this instance)

`findGood` returns a Promise so why not use [chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/)

```
it('good not found', function () { 
   var goodModelStub = sinon.stub(goodModel, 'findByName');

   var error = 'Good not found';

   goodModelStub.returns(Promise.reject(error));

   return goodFinder.findGood('Sony').should.be.rejected
  });
});
```