# Mocha promise test timout

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have the following test code in NodeJS:

```
'use strict';

// Example class to be tested
class AuthController {

    constructor() {
        console.log('Auth Controller test!');
    }

    isAuthorizedAsync(roles, neededRole) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return resolve(roles.indexOf(neededRole) >= 0);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = AuthController;
```

And the following mocha test code:

```
'use strict';

const assert         = require('assert');
const AuthController = require('../../lib/controllers/auth.controller');

describe('isAuthorizedAsync', () => {
    let authController = null;

    beforeEach(done =>  {
        authController = new AuthController();
        done();
    });

    it('Should return false if not authorized', function(done) {
        this.timeout(10000);    

        authController.isAuthorizedAsync(['user'], 'admin')
            .then(isAuth => {
                assert.equal(true, isAuth);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                throw(err);
                done();
            });
    });    
});
```

which throws the following error:

```
 1 failing

1) AuthController
    isAuthorizedAsync
      Should return false if not authorized:
  Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (c:\supportal\node_modules\ttm-module\test\controllers\auth.controller.spec.js)
```

I have tried increasing the default mocha test timeout to 10secs and made sure that the promise resolves. I am new to mocha. Am I missing something here?

Comment: as per my understanding, there's not issue with Mocha config.You need to resolved promise first in test case after that only you can test your suite

Comment: Ya I made sure that the promise resolves by console logging out a test message in the .then() block. Still seem to be getting this error, so not sure..

Comment: Like this spyOn(authController, 'isAuthorizedAsync').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

Comment: I found a workaround using chai-as-promised as discussed in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571328/how-do-i-properly-test-promises-with-mocha-and-chai. Is this the right approach?

Comment: chai-as-promised is mainly a convenience for people who don't want to do lots of promise chains in their tests. You certainly don't need it for this. You can use it, but I recommend making sure you understand how to do it normally as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not using the [mocha async API](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) correctly. To cause a failure with a `done` callback, you're supposed to provide an error as the first argument when you invoke it.

As written, your assertion in the `then` handler throws, which skips over the first `done` invocation and goes to the `catch` handler. That `catch` handler in turn re-throws that same error, similarly preventing you from ever reaching the second `done` callback.

What you get is an unhandled promise rejection and no invocation of `done`, leading to a mocha test timeout, possibly with a warning message about the unhandled rejection, depending on which version of node you're using.

Quickest fix would be to use the done callback correctly:

```
it('Should return false if not authorized', function(done) {
    authController.isAuthorizedAsync(['user'], 'admin')
        .then(isAuth => {
            assert.equal(true, isAuth);
            done();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            done(err); // Note the difference
        });
});
```

A much cleaner fix would be to use Mocha's built-in promise support by returning the chained promise. This removes the need to handle the failure case explicitly:

```
it('Should return false if not authorized', function() {
    return authController.isAuthorizedAsync(['user'], 'admin')
        .then(isAuth => {
            assert.equal(true, isAuth);
        });
});
```