# How to write a unit test for a function with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am a complete beginner with Node.JS and Mocha and was tasked to write unit test's for a group project. My problem is that i do not even know where to start since the  return value is a promise. 
Watching a lot of guides i have learned how to check return values for common functions but it wouldn't help me with a real world example.
If any expierienced developer could help me with a guide and code example specific to the function i listed i could hack and understand it and apply to other functions as well.
Here is a code example that get's statistics from a CSV File

```
function getStatistics() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        try {
            let readStatistics = [];
            const statisticsReadStream = fs.createReadStream(statisticsFileName);
            csv.fromStream(statisticsReadStream, {headers: true})
                .transform(function (data) {
                    data.avgDuration = parseFloat(data.avgDuration);
                    data.avgPassed = parseFloat(data.avgPassed);
                    data.avgReachedPoints = parseFloat(data.avgReachedPoints);
                    data.minReachedPoints = parseInt(data.minReachedPoints);
                    data.maxReachedPoints = parseInt(data.maxReachedPoints);
                    return data;
                })
                .on("data", function (data) {
                    readStatistics.push(data);
                })
                .on("end", function () {
                    resolve(readStatistics);
                    statisticsReadStream.close();
                });

        }catch(err){
            reject();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly test promises with mocha and chai?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571328/how-do-i-properly-test-promises-with-mocha-and-chai)

Comment: if i try the code provided by the article i get an error message: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

It does not really help me

Answer (score 1):

In mocha, you can return the promise from the test function to indicate that the test (`it`) has completed.

```
describe('My Test', function () {
  it('should do something cool', function () {
    return getStatistics().then(readStatistics => {
      // Assert whatever you want here
    });
  });
});
```

Any error that gets thrown from your `getStatistics` function or any assertion error will cause the test to fail.

If you are specifically looking to see if something throws an error, you can catch the error (`reject()`) in a test too.

```
describe('My Test', function () {
  it('should do something cool', function () {
    return getStatistics().catch(error => {
      // Assert whatever you want here about the error
    });
  });
});
```

https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: That is very useful, thank you!
I want to check wheter the transformationw orks correctly, however i get an error
  1) Statistic
       should transform data into strings:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
      at statGet.then.readStatistics (test.js:42:25)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
`describe('Statistic', function(){
  it('should transform data into strings', function () {
    return statGet().then(readStatistics => {
      let maybe = statGet();
      var csv = maybe.csv;

      let dat = function (data) {
        data.avgDuration = "1,2";
        data.avgPassed = "2,3";
        data.avgReachedPoints ="3,4";
        data.minReachedPoints = "4";
        data.maxReachedPoints = "5";
        return data;
      }
      assert.typeOf(csv.transform(dat, 'string'));
    });
  });
});`
```

on the other hand, i have liuttle idea of what i shold be testing in the first place.
I feel hopelessly lost. I want to go back to hello world =(