# Testing truthy / falsy values with assert/expect

Tags: javascript, jestjs, chai

when I write tests I often use such constructions with assert

```
 try {
   await asyncFunction(); // expect error
   assert(false) // to make 100% fail
 } catch (err) {
   assert(err) // means 'assert(true) 
 }
```

Now I need to use "expect" from chai lib and I don't know how to write exactly the same test with 'expect' syntax

Comment: Why are you using Chai's expect with Jest? It has its own [expectations](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect) (and [async handling](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)). Handling promises with _Mocha_ and Chai is well covered at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26571328/3001761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try

```
expect.fail("This should've not happenned");
```

or another "more readable" alternative

```
should.fail("This should've not happenned");
```

[Chai docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_fail)

In [this section](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) looks like there is a cool idiomatic way to perform what you want:

```js
const action = function() { yourSyncFunction() }
expect(action).to.throw(YourError)
```

And [here](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) there's the DSL for testing promises. (You need to install the "As promised" plugin)

```js
yourAsyncFunction().should.be.rejectedWith(Error)
```

Comment: `.to.throw` will not work - `action` _doesn't_ throw an error, it returns a rejected promise.

Comment: You're right. One should check for a rejected promise containing the error!

Comment: And note when handling promises it's critically important that they get settled _during the test_. Unless you return or await the promise, the assertion happens after the test has finished so the test can never fail.